# nesting anchor and override in yaml

Tags: yaml

I have the following yaml

```
f1.a: &f1-a
  docker: &docker-env
    image: someimage
    docker-run-arguments: &docker-run-args
      - -eenv1=a
      - -eenv2=b
      - -eenv3=c
```

I would like to create another section where I reuse most of the above but I override
some of the `-eenv` vars for example

```
f1.b: 
  <<: *f1.a
  docker: 
    <<: *docker-env
    docker-run-arguments: 
    <<: *docker-run-args
    - -eenv2=f
    - -eenv3=g
```

but the last 3 lines dont work (`expected a mapping for merging, but found scalar in 'reader' is the error`). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`*docker-run-args` references a sequence. The [merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html#:%7E:text=The%20%E2%80%9C%20%3C%3C%20%E2%80%9D%20merge%20key,inserted%20into%20the%20current%20map.) defines that

> If the value associated with the merge key is a sequence, then this sequence is expected to contain mapping nodes and each of these nodes is merged in turn according to its order in the sequence.

and the items in the sequence you give are not mapping nodes, but scalar nodes (`-eenv1=a` etc).

The more general error is that you try to merge sequences, which isn't what the merge key does – it merges mappings. `<<:` is a mapping key and can thus occur only in mappings. `<<` is not any special YAML syntax, it's just a scalar that is given a special meaning by semantics, and those semantics are only defined for YAML 1.1 and outside the spec so don't expect it to work with all implementations, most of which have been implemented against YAML 1.2.